# Why are We Moved from the Threads Closures are called On in Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am learning about Grand Central Dispatch in Swift.  I've learned that you are able to create your own queues to execute code on.  I've also learned that you can return to the main thread by calling main.  I've been using breakpoints to watch the threads as code is executed trying to better understand GCD.  I am noticing the following and trying to make sense of it.

1. I've created my own queue called downloadQueue.  I am calling dataTask from URLSession on this queue and am seeing that when on the line that calls dataTask() I am in the downloadQueue I created.

[image]

2. The minute I enter the completion handler of dataTask() I am no longer on downloadQueue.  I am moved to Queue: NSOperationQueue.

[image]

The code below is my dataTask().

```
let downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "downloadQueue", attributes: [])
```

downloadQueue.async { () -> Void in

```
    let dataTask = self.session!.dataTask(with: self.sessionURL!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    
    if error == nil
    {
        if data != nil
        {
            // Handle Data
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
    else if error != nil
    {
        self.sendErrorCodeEmail(errorCodeMessage)  // The line from image2
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

}

My understanding was that all code placed in the downloadQueue.async{} closure was executed on downloadQueue.  Why am I moved to another queue?

3. The same thing holds true if I make a call back to the main thread.  I am placed back on Queue: NSOperationQueue once I enter the DispatchQueue.main.async{} closure.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why" questions are always a little funny.  In the most direct sense, [because that's just how URLSession works](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1411571-delegatequeue):

> All delegate method calls and completion handlers related to the session are performed on this queue.